Understanding the definition of compactly generated space
A compactly generated space (or a $k$-space) is a topological space $X$ where every subset $A\subset X$ is open iff, for every compact subset $K\subset X$, the intersection $A\cap K$ is open in the subspace topology of $K$.
Question. By the definition of subspace/relative topology, if subset $A$ is open, isn't it guaranteed $A\cap B$ is relatively open in every subset $B$ of $X$? So should I understand the above definition as this: a subset $A$ must be open in $X$ if, for every compact subset $K$, there is an open subset $A_K$ s.t. $A\cap K= A_K\cap K$?
Hope it makes sense. Thanks in advance.

Yes, this is correct. The other direction indeed always holds.

@Mark Thanks! That's a relief.
